# Is there a JSONP image search API that I can use to have users search for images on my site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsonp

I'm building some sort of blog website.
I want people to type in words in my website and search for images, straight on my site.  Then I can grab the URL of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try flicker. They have jsonp.